# Jackson XML map repeating element groups

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Using Jackson, I have to create a java class that can be marshaled to following XML

```
<Root>
   <Key>key1</Key>
   <Value>value1</Value>
   <Key>key2</Key>
   <Value>value2</Value>
   ...
</Root>
```

Following class is closed but the order of `Key` and `Value` is not correct.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Root")
class Root {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Key")
    private String[] keys;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Value")
    private String[] values;
}
```

How to create a class that maps to repeating element pairs with correct order?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631031/jaxb-jackson-sequence-of-two-elements-without-parent-tag)  might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! with the help of custom serializer.

First, the root element:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Root")
class Root {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Wrapper> keyValueList;
    // getters, setters
}
```

The wrapper class for `Key` and `Value` pairs:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = WrapperSerializer.class)
class Wrapper {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    // getters, setters, all args constructors
}
```

And the serializer:

```
public class WrapperSerializer extends StdSerializer<Wrapper> {
    public WrapperSerializer() {
        this(Wrapper.class);
    }

    protected WrapperSerializer(Class<Wrapper> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Wrapper value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeRaw(new StringBuilder()
                .append("<Key>")
                .append(value.getKey())
                .append("</Key>")
                .append("<Value>")
                .append(value.getValue())
                .append("</Value>")
                .toString());
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
Root ref = new Root();
ref.setKeyValueList(Arrays.asList(
        new Wrapper("k1", "v1"),
        new Wrapper("k2", "v2")));
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String output = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(ref);
System.out.println(output);
```

The result:

```
<Root><Key>k1</Key><Value>v1</Value><Key>k2</Key><Value>v2</Value></Root>
```